# How to rename downloaded youtube playlist via youtube-dl

Tags: rename, youtube-dl

I have already downloaded a YouTube playlist, I didn't think of renaming it while downloading.
Now, I need to rename all the videos as per playlist numbering. I found this to do so

```
 youtube-dl -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s" <playlist_link>
```

But it will download the playlist again which I don't want. So I tried to use the different options like `--skip-download` without success. I read the `youtube-dl -h` to find a solution, but I can't seem to find. I am stuck in here any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think youtube-dl has an option for renaming while downloading. You can use [Flash Renamer](https://www.rlvision.com/flashren/about.php) or something similar after the downloading has completed, it is very easy and useful.